# from mobaxterm tunnel to ssh command line

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

The next picture was used to create a tunnel with mobaxterm:

[image]

Does anyone knows the meaning? also, how can I do to translate this into Ubuntu Linux ssh command to create the tunnel specified by the picture?. I need this to connect to my db.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks roughly like

```
ssh myusername@grv.soccer.cpu.edu -p 7822 -L 1338:172.178.0.12:3338
```

which basically means: connect to `grv.soccer.cpu.edu` using username `myusername`, the server is using port `7822` instead of the default port `22` and, while you are it, put local port `1338` in LISTEN and tunnel-it to port `3338` of server/IP `172.178.0.12`; after you've successfully connected to the `grv.soccer.cpu.edu` you'll have the service running on `172.178.0.12:3338` directly reachable locally on/at `127.0.0.1:1338`.